# POST parameter not recognized in curl request to API

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I built an API that takes in a post param of a hardware version.
Everything was working fine on my other machine and am trying to get a new laptop set up with the repo. Now when I call curl -d "my_param=10" url_here it is showing that the value I post to the api is null. Is there a reason this would happen? I have CURL installed and php.. I know the code is sound, so it's a setup issue somewhere, but not sure what would cause this.

```
command: curl --data "hardware_version=10" http://localhost/api/hw/123-456

previous os: Ubuntu
current os: OS X
```

Comment: Shoudnt your parameter be a json  {"my_param":"10"} ?Show your code anyway

Comment: nope that is not a requirement

Comment: Please post the exact command (URL is not mandatory). Also post your machine OS for previous and new one. Also, try to run the command with verbose mode by adding `-v` to see what is happening.

Comment: Updated with more info @SabujHassan